# Natural basis element of $(Fun(X,\mathbb{C}))^G$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take $X=G$ with the action of $G$ by left multiplication.
I need to prove that the space of invariants of the set of all maps from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$, namely $(Fun(X,\mathbb{C}))^G$, is one-dimensional and to give a natural basis element candidate.
I have found that all functions on $G$ which are invariant under left multiplication must be constant as left multiplication is a transitive action.
I believe that this brings me close to an answer, but I cannot finish the proof as I am not quite sure what a basis would even look like.
Would $f(e)=e$ be a basis consisting of one element thus proving one-dimensionality?

Comment: $f(e)=e$ makes no sense, as $f$ should be a function $G\to\mathbb{C}$. You have found that all the functions in the space are constant functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$, so now choose one to get a basis. (Hint: only one such function will not work, all others will)

Comment: I think I understand - any function $f:G\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ would work?

Comment: Any constant function $G\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, yes. Of course, the most natural choice is the constant function $f\equiv 1$.

Comment: For context see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554145/space-of-invariants-funx-mathbbcg-isomorphic-to-funx-g-mathbbc).